# Arduino can't multiply?

Tags: arduino-uno, c

I have a value I'm taking from a sensor module, which is 2500 when the sensor is facing a light source. This reads to my code and can be saved perfectly fine. When I try to find the weighted average of a set of values (2500*1000+2500*2000+2500*3000 etc), the Arduino comes out with very weird answers. For example

2500*1000=9632

If I just compute 2500*1000 on its own, the answer still comes out the same! The results come out negative if I use int so I switched to using double (just in case the values created were too big), this stops producing negatives as expected but the result is still like it is above.. I have no idea why.. any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it! The problem is that if you multiply a double by an int it turns into an int... I was using doubles for everything but then my weight was using the counter variable, i (e.g. 1000*(i+1)).. This turned the end result back into an int!

Comment: No. double × int → double. Actually, “doubles” are just floats on Arduino (32 bit, i.e. single precision).

Comment: Hmm, but then why did this happen:

val(double)*weight(double)*(i(int)+1) = the integer result and not the double? 

Even though it was stored in a variable defined as a double.. Im trying to describe the problem in a way that will help people stuck with the same issue because this had me confused for ages

Comment: Show your code -- it could be how the results or intermediate results are stored.

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < NUM_SENSORS; j++)
  {
    sensorTotal+=sensorValues[j]; //This works
    sensorWeighted+=sensorValues[j]*1000*(j+1); //This dosent
  }
  problem fixed by casting the j inside (j+1) to a double.

Comment: Makes little sense to me. If sensorValues[j] is int, (sensorValues[j] * 1000) will be computed as an int, no matter what you have in the next multiplication. You should probably show a little more of your code (at least the relevant declarations with the types). Add that to the question, indented by four spaces.

Comment: (2500*1000) % 2^16 = 9632

Answer (score 4):

2500 * 1000 = 9632 is exactly what you expect with 16-bit integers. You
should use long integers instead:

```
2500L * 1000L == 2500000L
```

Floats work also, but are more expensive:

```
2500.0 * 1000.0 == 2500000.0
```

although I do not recommend testing for exact equality of floats (it
works here because these numbers are exactly representable).